# 'PolyCollection' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

So the error I'm getting is `TypeError: 'PolyCollection' object is not callable`. *How do I fix this?*

I am trying to create a dynamically updated histogram with Python and Matplotlib, displayed using Tkinter. As you can see in my code below, I am using Matplotlib's `hexbin` function to create the graphs by passing in several lists; ages, weights, and heights. The `UpdateGraph` method I have created is an infinite loop spawned on a separate `thread` that checks to see if new data is ready to be graphed. If it is, then it jumps back to the `main thread`and updates the graphs by clearing them, plotting the data, adding the axis titles back and then drawing the canvas.

**Creation of the Graphs** (I'm pretty sure all of this is ok and isn't causing any issues.)

```
#avh = Age Vs Height
#wvh = Weight Vs Height

self.xLimit = (0,8)
self.avhYLimit = (0,99)
self.wvhYLimit = (0,300)
self.avhExtent = self.xLimit + self.avhYLimit
self.wvhExtent = self.xLimit + self.wvhYLimit

self.avhGraphFrame = Frame(frame)
self.avhGraphFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = N+S+E+W)
self.avhFigure = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize = (7,5), frameon = False)
self.avhCanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.avhfigure , master = self.avhGraphFrame)
self.avhPlot = self.avhFigure.add_subplot(111)
self.avhPlot.set_xlim(self.xLimit)
self.avhPlot.set_ylim(self.avhYLimit )
self.avhCanvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = Tkinter.LEFT, fill = Tkinter.BOTH, expand = 1)

self.wvhGraphFrame = Frame(frame)
self.wvhGraphFrame.grid(row = 3, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = N+S+E+W)
self.wvhFigure = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize = (7,5), frameon = False)
self.wvhCanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.wvhFigure , master = self.wvhGraphFrame)
self.wvhPlot = self.wvhFigure.add_subplot(111)
self.wvhPlot.set_xlim(self.xLimit)
self.wvhPlot.set_ylim(self.wvhExtent)
self.wvhCanvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = Tkinter.LEFT, fill = Tkinter.BOTH, expand = 1)
```

**Update Graph Method**

```
def UpdateGraphs(self):
    while True:
        dataFinalIndex = len(self.mainController.PDWs)

        ages    = []
        weights = []
        heights = []

        for person in self.persons:
            ages.append(person.age)
            weights.append(person.weight)
            heights.append(person.height)

        root.after_idle(self.avhplot.clear)
        root.after_idle(self.wvhPlot.clear)

        """ Here is where the error comes from"""
        root.after_idle(self.avhplot.hexbin(heights, ages, cmap = matplotlib.cm.jet,
                                            mincnt = 1, bins = "log", extent = self.avhExtent))
        root.after_idle(self.avhplot.hexbin(heights, weights, cmap = matplotlib.cm.jet,
                                            mincnt = 1, bins = "log", extent = self.wvhExtent))
        """             End of Error          """

        root.after_idle(self.avhPlot.set_ylabel, ("Ages")
        #The rest of the labels are set like this as well

        root.after_idle(self.avhCanvas.draw)
        root.after_idle(self.wvhCanvas.draw)
```

The error is getting thrown when I try to plot the data. I have no idea why this is happening because this has worked in the past. The weird thing is that it will graph the data the first time (even with the error) but not the second time.

**Stack Trace**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 495, in callit
    func(*args)
TypeError: 'PolyCollection' object is not callable
```

Note: All of the code above is just sample. If there are any typos, they are non existent in my actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was -

I assumed I would need to jump back to the main thread to graph the data, but for some reason adding `root.add_idle` before the functions to clear and plot the data was unnecessary and causing the issue.

**Corrected Code**

```
    self.avhplot.hexbin(heights, ages, cmap = matplotlib.cm.jet,
                                        mincnt = 1, bins = "log", extent = self.avhExtent)
    self.avhplot.hexbin(heights, weights, cmap = matplotlib.cm.jet,
                                        mincnt = 1, bins = "log", extent = self.wvhExtent)
```